# DateTime Conversion to Epoch Time

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, epoch

I need to convert time stored in a variable in the format using Python <=2.7

```
07/20-10:38:04.360700
```

to epoch time (since Midnight, Jan 1st, 1970) like this

```
1405852684.360700
```

Is it best to import the time module, or just split and use some math calculations?

Comment: Do you want to figure it out yourself, or use something that definitely already works? If you're learning, consider the latter, otherwise standard library every time.

Comment: What is the timezone? Is it local time or UTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string date is with respect to UTC, then:

```
In [31]: import datetime as DT

In [32]: text = '07/20-10:38:04.360700'

In [33]: date = DT.datetime.strptime('2014/'+text, '%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S.%f')

In [34]: (date - DT.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
Out[34]: 1405852684.3607
```

If the string date refers to a date with respect to some other timezone, then you could use [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) to make the datetime timezone-aware before doing the calculation. For example,

```
import pytz
import datetime as DT

text = '07/20-10:38:04.360700'
tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
date = DT.datetime.strptime('2014/'+text, '%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S.%f')
# interpret the date as coming from US/Eastern
date_tz = tz.localize(date) 

epoch = DT.datetime(1970,1,1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
timestamp = (date_tz - epoch).total_seconds()
print(repr(timestamp))
# 1405867084.3607
```

Comment: Thats excellent. I just have a problem setting the time zone, as the calculation is an hour off. I need the results as GMT+1

Comment: @MPythonLearner: the timestamp in your question suggests that your timezone has zero UTC offset on 2014-07-10 i.e., it can't be "GMT+1" at the same time.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian : you're right. I've removed my comment, and updated my previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's [`timetuple()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.timetuple) function (and a little math)

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> v = datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 20, 10, 38, 4, 360700)
>>> time.mktime(v.timetuple())
1405870684.0
```

Now we need your microseconds:

```
>>> time.mktime(v.timetuple())+(v.microsecond/1000000.)
1405870684.3607
```

Comment: it assumes that `v` is a local time. Local time is ambigous and therefore the result may be wrong 50% of the time during DST transitions. It also assumes that `time.gmtime(0)` is 1970-01-01

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the year so here I assume that it is the current year. The following assumes that all times are UTC, i.e. not local time.

```
from datetime import datetime

time_string = '07/20-10:38:04.360700'
dt = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%m/%d-%H:%M:%S.%f')
dt = dt.replace(year=datetime.today().year)

>>> (dt - datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()
1405852684.3607
```

Comment: How would I save the output of this to 9 decimal places? i.e. I need the epoch time number to read something like 1405816684.360700000, I need the zeros at the end for comparison reasons

Comment: The first formula works if `dt` is a UTC time. The second formula (assuming `dt` is a local time) may break if UTC offset has changed between `gmtime(0)` and `dt` local time e.g., if the local timezone observes DST. You should use [@Andy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25472595/4279) instead. Both answers are wrong if `time.gmtime(0)` is not 1970-01-01